# Qt, start and stop Thread with signals

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals

I have a problem with my Qt Thread and it's signals.
I'm creating a QObject called dworker and move it to a QThread and then start the thread with a click on my start button.
It's basicly just updating the GUI with some numbers and is supposed to stop when i press the stop button. Well it stops but the "qDebug() << "thread stopping = " << stop;" in dworker isn't called and i can't start it again. The signal is triggert but the slot methode isn't executed.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

namespace GLOBAL
{
    Settings mSettings;
    Data mData;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dthread = new QThread(this);
   dworker = new Dworker();
   dworker->moveToThread(dthread);

    connect(dworker, SIGNAL(set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)),
            this, SLOT(slot_set_values(double,double,double,double,double,double)));
    connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), dworker, SLOT(slot_process()));
    connect(ui->stopButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), dworker, SLOT(slot_end_process()));

    dthread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slot_set_values(double ptm_temp, double ptm_hv, double heat_temp, double nomtemp, double current, double voltage)
{
    ui->pmtValueLabel->setText(QString::number(ptm_temp));
    ui->hvValueLabel->setText(QString::number(ptm_hv));
    ui->heatValueLabel->setText(QString::number(heat_temp));
    ui->nomValueLabel->setText(QString::number(nomtemp));
    ui->currenValueLabel->setText(QString::number(current));
    ui->vValueLabel->setText(QString::number(voltage));

    //qDebug() <<"set_values SLOT " <<ptm_temp<<" "<<ptm_hv<<" "<<heat_temp<<" "<<nomtemp<<" "<<current<<" "<<voltage;

}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    dworker->stop = true;
    qDebug() << "send stop";
}
```

dworker.cpp:

```
#include "dworker.h"

using namespace GLOBAL;

QMutex mutex;

Dworker::Dworker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

void Dworker::slot_process()
{
    stop = false;

    while (true)
    {

        mutex.lock();
        if(stop) break;
        mutex.unlock();

        qsrand(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t());
        mData.set_pmt_temp(qrand()%100);
        mData.set_pmt_hv(qrand()%100);
        mData.set_heat_opt_temp(qrand()%100);
        mData.set_heat_nominal_temp(qrand()%100);

        double pmt_tmp = mData.get_pmt_temp();
        double hv = mData.get_pmt_hv();
        double heat_temp = mData.get_heat_opt_temp();
        double heat_nom = mData.get_heat_nominal_temp();

        emit set_values(pmt_tmp,hv,heat_temp,heat_nom,0,0);

        QThread::msleep(1000);
        qDebug() <<"Thread SIGNAL " <<pmt_tmp<<" "<<hv<<" "<<heat_temp<<" "<<heat_nom;
    }
}

void Dworker::slot_end_process()
{
    mutex.lock();
    stop = true;
    mutex.unlock();

    qDebug() << "thread stopping = " << stop;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of problems!

You are using default value in connect `Qt::AutoConnection`. This means that if signal is passed between treads through event loop of destination thread, see [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). This is why you can't stop your function, your event loop is never gains control when `slot_process()` is running. To fix it change connect like this (use `Qt::DirectConnection`):

```
connect(ui->stopButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), 
        dworker, SLOT(slot_end_process())
        Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Another problem: you are locking mutex incorrectly in `slot_process()`, note that break will skip unlock and mutex will remain locked permanently, fix it like this:

```
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    if(stop) break;
} // braces are important
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're so right with the mutex! I just didn't see that. Changed it to: mutex.lock();
        if(stop) {mutex.unlock(); break;}
        mutex.unlock();

Comment: @Marek R: Is this healthy? Qt::AutoConnection turns into Qt::QueuedConnection for a reason when sender and receiver are in different threads. Forcing it to Qt::DirectConnection is probably no good idea. Or you know **really** good what you are doing with mutexes.

Comment: if you want to break this loop by changing  value of `stop` you have to enforce DirectConnection for `slot_end_process` slot. It is safe since you have mutex there and `slot_end_process` is thread safe. I explained why: in case of Qt::QueuedConnection thread must reach event loop to process queued slots.

Comment: @MarekR In this case though, it's really silly to have a while loop that contains `QThread::sleep(1000)` in it. The while loop should be removed and it should be replaced with a `QTimer`. That way `Qt::DirectConnection` would not be needed. [Like it says here.](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e)

Comment: Ok if the while loop is a bad idea, how should I replace it? I don't know how what QTimer does.